# django python conditional not working?

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements

I have this code in django and when I print it in the console it outputs user_id = 1 and request.user.id = 1

so the url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/picturelist/1`, which makes user_id = 1, then I logged-in to my superuser I created when I start my project in django which is request.user.id = 1

why am I getting permissionDenied?

```
def pictureList(request, user_id):
    if user_id != request.user.id:
        print "%s, %s " % (user_id, request.user.id)
        raise PermissionDenied
    picture_list = Picture.objects.filter(user=user_id)
    print "%s, %s " % (user_id, request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: `user_id` is a string, while `request.user.id` is an `int`.

Comment: thanks, I added int() to user_id and it worked. if int(user_id) != request.user.id: